# How to know which versions of application I can install via apt

Tags: 11.04, apt, gnome, gedit

I try to use

```
apt-cache search gedit
```

But there is no information about version.

I am trying to install gedit 2.30.4 (by default it is 3.x on Gnome 3). But there is no gedit with this version.

```
sudo apt-get install gedit=2.30.4
#=> Error
```

So how can I figure out which versions are in repo?

Comment: The `=` in your command seems suspicious. I'd expect a `-`.

Comment: I read manuals about it and there was equal sign `=` for version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `policy` command of `apt-cache` displays the current installed and available versions.

```
apt-cache policy gedit
```